# Iniciar workrave al encender equipo con Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian

Tengo instalado el programa **workrave** para pausas activas en mi computador con Sistema Operativo: **Debian Jessie**, pero cada vez que lo prendo debo iniciarlo manualmente ya que en las preferencias no tiene la opción para marcar de iniciar automáticamente. Quiero saber: ¿De que forma puedo configurarlo para que inicie con el encendido de la maquina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- En la parte superior izquierda para ver las **Aplicaciones**
- Busca las **Herramientas de retoque**
- Allí se puede ver una opción que dice **Aplicaciones al inicio**, aquí podrías agregar la aplicación que desees se inicio con el sistema.

Comment: Gracias amigo, no conocía esta herramienta, esta muy completa, me sirvió para solucionar mi problema y ademas tiene mas opciones de personalización que voy a probar :D

Comment: De nada, amigo :D